# What is the relationship of my brother's son to my wife's brother's daughter?

Tags: kinship-terms

I need to introduce my nephew (my brother's son) to my nieces (my wife's brother's daughters). They're related, but only through marriage. How do I introduce them?

Comment: [Name of nephew] this is [name of one niece], she is my wife's niece, and this is her younger/older sister [name].

Comment: Have you done any research into this matter?

Comment: No, thanks, just starting; the problem is possibly about to surface. Are they cousins, or are they cousins-in-law?

Comment: [A cousin is a relative with whom a person shares one or more common ancestors. In the general sense, cousins are two or more generations away from any common ancestor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin)

Comment: They are unrelated to one another.

Comment: Well, since one is MaieEgo's MaleSib's child and the other are MaleEgo's Wife's MaleSib's child, they're cross-cousins. If it matters; in our kinship system, we don't distinguish cross- from ortho-cousins. But lots of other cultures do. @Ricky's answer is correct -- they're cousins; however, there are different kinds of cousins and they'll hafta figure out what kinds they are.

Answer (score 0):

"Cousin" is widely accepted to mean pretty much any member of the extended family.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cousin?s=t

Comment: Where does it say that *cousin* is used for two people  unrelated by blood? If the OP and his wife separate, will the nephew and nieces still be called *cousins*?

Comment: Yeah, although separation is not likely; plus I was looking for something a little more specific.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think what he means is that *cousin* is loosely used to mean such as that. But obviously so far as strict relationships are concerned, cousins have a common ancestor.

Comment: English has got more, rather than less, picky about kinship terms in the last couple of hundred years. In 19th century novels, _sister_ is often used to mean _sister in law_ or even _brother's sister in law_, and _cousin_ as Ricky says. But I suspect that some of this precision is just the compilers and users of reference books wanting definite answers, and that many people ignore the definitions and carry on using words more loosely.